# Save JSON output to a json file

Tags: php, json

Got this code:

```
<?php
  $jsonurl = "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=cnn&sortBy=top&apiKey=d8dfc55aa005430c9567416cac34e3fa";
  $json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
  var_dump(json_decode($json));

          $file = fopen('news.json','w');
          fwrite($file, $json);
          fclose($file);
```

But nothing gets saved to the new `news.json` file, why would this be? As I was taught - creating files is done using this method. (`w` on `fopen`)

Comment: working fine at my end

Comment: Working fine php 7.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check the write permissions in your directory. Specify also the absolute path to the news.json file, because it seems like your PHP server can't read the relative path :

Change

```
$file = fopen('news.json','w');
```

to

```
$file = fopen(__DIR__ . '/news.json','w');
```

Answer (score 2):

enable php errors to see the issue, do you see data in var_dump(could be SSL thing)?
also check permissions on `news.json` file